# Homebrewed python gtk import results in segmentation fault

Tags: python, gtk, segmentation-fault, pygtk, homebrew

I am trying to get my brewed version of python to work with the brewed gtk. However, I get this error. I can't find the problem that is causing this issue. This error occurs after pygtk is installed.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import gtk
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gio/__init__.py:23: Warning: g_str_has_prefix: assertion `str != NULL' failed
    from _gio import *
Segmentation fault: 11
```

The versions gtk and pygtk packages installed are gtk+-2.24.20 and pygtk: stable 2.24.0.

My list of brew installed packages is:

```
atk         gdk-pixbuf  jpeg        pango       pygobject
cairo       gettext     libffi      pcre        pygtk
cmake       glib        libpng      pixman      python
fontconfig  gtk+        libtiff     pkg-config  readline
freetype    harfbuzz    nginx       postgresql  sqlite
gdbm        icu4c       ossp-uuid   py2cairo    xz
```

Answer (score 0):

The same problem for me when I am trying to launch zim note app. OS X has own python which linked to /usr/bin/python and brew link own compiled python in /usr/local/bin/python.

With Apple's python I can launch zim app but It crashes on double click (two-fingers tap).

With Brew's python I cant launch Zim at all. Shell show me the same error:

```
python /Users/md760/my_apps/zim-0.62/zim.py
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gio/__init__.py:23: Warning: g_str_has_prefix: assertion `str != NULL' failed
  from _gio import *
Segmentation fault: 11
```

So at least creating ticket to brew githab is good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this error can appear when you were installed few gtk (pygtk) libs. For example one from brew repo and another from any dmg or like that.

So I can advise you to remove one of them, for example non-brew version:

```
# rm -rf /opt/gtk
```

And then try to import gtk in python